# How do i trace multiple XML elements with same name & without any id?

Tags: google-sheets, xpath

I am trying to scrape a website for financials of Indian companies as a side project & put it in **Google Sheets using XPATH**

**Link:** https://ticker.finology.in/company/AFFLE

I am able to extract data from elements that have a specific id like cash, net debt, etc. however I am stuck with extracting data for labels like Sales Growth.

**tried**
Copying the full xpath from console, **//*[@id="mainContent_updAddRatios"]/div[13]/p/span** - this works, however, i am reliable on the index of the div (13) and that may change for different companies, hence i am unable to automate it.

Please assist with a scalable solution

**PS: I am a Product Manager with basic coding expertise as I was a developer few years ago.**

Answer (score 1):

At some point you need to "hardcode" something unless you have some other means of mapping the content of the page to your spreadsheet.  In your example you appear to be targeting "Sales Growth" percentage.  If you are not comfortable hardcoding the index of the div (13), you could identify it by the id of the "Sales Growth" label which is mainContent_lblSalesGrowthorCasa.

For example, change your

```
//*[@id="mainContent_updAddRatios"]/div[13]/p/span
```

to:

```
//*[@id = "mainContent_updAddRatios"]/div[.//span/@id = "mainContent_lblSalesGrowthorCasa"]/p/span
```

which is selecting the div based on the div containing a span with id="mainContent_lblSalesGrowthorCasa".  Ultimately, whether you "hardcode" the exact index of the div or "hardcode" the ids of the nodes, you are still embedding assumptions regarding the structure of page.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @david, that helped.

**Two questions**

1. What if the structure of the page would change? Example: If the website decided to remove the p tag then would my sheet fail? How do we avoid failure in such cases?
   Also, since every id is unique, the probability of that getting changed is lesser than the index being changed. Correct me, if I am wrong?
2. What do we do when the elements don't have an id like Profit Growth, RoE, RoCE etc

Comment: Please don't create an answer to ask additional questions.  This is better addressed through comments to my answer or as a new question since you're effectively asking for help with design strategies on top of the specific question originally asked.

Comment: As implied by my original answer, you can certainly analyze the page structure for different ways to identify the data elements you need (and not all approaches may work for all data elements) but unless the page publisher has agreed to some maintain certain conventions, a simple XPath approach will always be fragile and subject to failure whenever the publisher makes changes.  Beyond that, a more sophisticated approach to intelligently understand the page's content regardless of structure would require a lot more than a handful of XPath expressions.

Comment: Similar XPath for Profit Growth which searches for the div containing, anywhere within, the text "Profit Growth" instead of "hardcoding" the index of the div (16): //*[@id="mainContent_updAddRatios"]/div[contains(.//*,"Profit Growth")]/p/span/text()

Comment: Apologies. Returning to SO after a long time, hence the answer & comment weren't easily distinguishable.

Comment: can you throw some more light or examples/illustrations to understand what would be the sophisticated approach?

Comment: contains works well. I used that for all the elements in that table. Thanks a ton :) Now I can proceed with other sections. Let me try that & ask another question if i need more help.